# Can I kill a process from itself?

Tags: c, unix, process

I have some code that is executed when the process is killed, can I actually call `kill(getpid())` to force the execution of this code (and close the process obviously)?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just `exit()`?

Comment: Couldn't you just add a function in that calls the code you want to perform before it exits and then call `exit()`? Since you need to process that code first.

Comment: An alternative approach to this could involve using [`on_exit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/on_exit)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, you can.  There's even a specific function for it — [`raise(sig)`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Signaling-Yourself.html#Signaling-Yourself) — although `kill(getpid(), sig)` will work too.

Comment: I noticed this new answer only today but I think it's better.

Comment: Just a word of caution: if you use this in a multi threaded environment and you want to send a signal to your signal handling thread `raise(sig)` will not work because. The man page states:
The raise() function sends a signal to the calling process or thread.
In a single-threaded program it is equivalent to `kill(getpid(), sig);`
In a multithreaded program it is equivalent to `pthread_kill(pthread_self(), sig);`
If the signal causes a handler to be called, raise() will return only after the signal handler has returned.

Comment: @FrancescoBelladonna Doesn't `kill(0, some_sig)` also work?

Comment: Discovered today that I indeed need to use kill(getpid(), sig) instead of raise(sig) from my thread. Thanks @Kratz

Answer (score 8):

you can call your own process using kill through:

```
kill(getpid(),SIGINT);
```

For more information take a look at [this](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node24.html)

> This would have a similar effect to exit() command.

Comment: I would like to point out that kill(getpid(), SIGINT) DOES NOT have the same effect as exit().

Comment: raising SIGINT, unlike exit(), will transfer the process control to any registered handler, and also it might result in a core-dump file - to name a couple of the differences between exit() and raising a SIGINT.

Comment: @AhmedMasud That's why the text in the link said similar and not same ("Same" means they are Identical with no differences, "similar" means they are almost identical but have some minor differences) ;)

Answer (score 6):

Try `exit` - a lot simpler - why make things complicated?

Comment: As I wrote in my question it's because I'm handling some code through signals and I want make the exit code standard, any problem in killing process through kill so?

Comment: You can give an exit code. Just use the signal handling to tidy up then exit with a status code.

Comment: There is at least one case when using `exit()` is not desirable: after a `fork` where the child tries to `exec` another program, but fails (for whatever reason). Calling `exit` in the child causes routines installed by `on_exit` to be executed, which causes unwanted side effects since only the parent process should do that stuff (e.g. closing a database connection).

Answer (score 3):

I suspect there's a larger problem with your design choices.

If you want to execute some code when your process terminates, register the code with `atexit`.

That said, yes, you can send your own process a signal with `kill(getpid(), sig)`.

Comment: It's not a design, it's a workaround for fixing a design change

Comment: Well, it *is* a design choice. If you have to create a workaround like this, you should re-examine your original design choices.

Comment: It was something that weren't requested, that's why I thought about this workaround, however they changed their mind about this another time and I had to change a lot of things, I'm going mad

Comment: one use case of sending a `SIGINT` to yourself is e.g. in an assert macro when you run the application in a debugger. When an assertion fails, the debugger will become active and you can inspect the call stack, values of variables etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use kill(getpid(), SIGSPEC) to do this properly to execute the code that's actually installed as a signal handler for any particular signal specified by SIGSPEC.

You cannot of course capture SIGKILL or SIGSTOP those cannot have handlers. All other signals can have handlers installed using the signal code.

If the handler code is not a signal handler but an atexit handler then it will only be called via exit() call. Note that _exit() call bypasses all atexit handlers.

Also i see a few comments here that seem to suggest that kill(getpid(), SIGSPEC) is the same as _exit() or exit() IT IS NOT! They are different things.

My suggestion would be to read exit(3) _exit(2) signal(7) signal(2) raise(3) sigaction(3) man pages for a complete understanding.

Answer (score 0):

A process can kill itself in a following way:
kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);