# Why does child process leak memory in C after killing it?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, fork, free, child-process

I need to terminate the child process at the end of the (if) block. However killing it causes memory leak
Tried on ubuntu terminal.

```
compile:  gcc -W -Wall -Wextra mallocFork.c
```

run: valgrind ./a.out

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{
    int *numbers = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    numbers[0] = 1;
    numbers[1] = 2;
    numbers[2] = 4;
    int child = fork();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
    }

    if (child == 0)
    {
        free(numbers);
        kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
    }

    free(numbers);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried using free but didn't work.[memory leak]        (https://i.stack.imgur.com/55H5s.png)

Comment: please don't share text as screenshots.  Copy the text and paste it as text into the question's text.

Comment: Why are you making the child to kill itself? Why not simply `rerurn` or `exit` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851121/can-i-kill-a-process-from-itself

Comment: I think the problem is that the parent is exiting before the child, so when it exits the child's allocation hasn't been freed yet. Does it work better if the parent calls `wait()`?

Comment: Thank you. With exit(0) and wait() everything works fine.

Comment: huh???? this screenshot says no leaks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is your parent process is finishing before your child process, and you don't wait for your child process to end.

You can use the wait function from <sys/wait> in the parent process to wait for the child to finish executing like so:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    int *numbers = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    numbers[0] = 1;
    numbers[1] = 2;
    numbers[2] = 4;
    int child = fork();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
    }

    if (child == 0)
    {
        free(numbers);
        return 0;
    }

    free(numbers);
    wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

if you want to get the return value from the child process, you can pass an integer into the wait function instead of NULL, and that integer value will be the value returned by the child process

```c
int child_result;
wait(&child_result);
```

when I compiled and ran valgrind with the program, I had no memory leak errors.

Comment: Beware of `return` from `main()` or `exit()` from a child process.  The child will inherit `FILE *` streams **and their buffers** from the parent process as they were at the moment of calling `fork()`, and returning from `main()` or calling `exit()` from the child processes risks flushing those buffers into the *parent's* files/streams.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Would you suggest calling fflush(<stream>) before returning/exiting? Or is there a better alternative than returning or exiting, in order to avoid the case of the child flushing those streams and buffers into the parent's?